# File not found when running pdflatex, but is found using 'tlmgr info'

Tags: pdftex

New to LaTeX, just installed MacTeX, attempting to convert legacy .tex file to .pdf.

Attempting to create pdf with :
    pdflatex doc.tex

This doc contains the line :
    `\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}`

Get error :

> ! LaTeX Error: File `carlito.sty' not
>   found.

Have previously installed this font using :
    `sudo tlmgr install carlito`

Running `tlmgr info carlito` seems to return valid descriptive data.

Why can `tlmgr` find my font, but pdflatex can't?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Does `kpsewhich carlito.sty` find it (run it as you own used, **not** under `sudo`. BTW: Are you sure you installed MacTeX, because MacTeX should already include `carlito.sty`

Comment: I'll add that I'm not having a problem using that package and font. Do you have more than one TeX distribution; what does `which pdflatex` return?

Comment: `kpsewhich carlito.sty` returns nothing, and `which pdflatex` gives /opt/local/bin/pdflatex

Comment: I installed latex from http://www.tug.org/mactex/

Comment: I don't think that I have more than one TeX distribution. Is there an easy way to tell?